# Adding custom attribute to a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm using a libary for creating a donut shaped pie chart.

https://www.numetriclabz.com/donut-chart-tutorial-using-numandroidcharts-library-tutorial/

In this provided tutorial under step 4 there is a custom attribute called **custom:pieInnerCircleRatio** being added to the donut chart item. However there is no specific explanation written, on how that is done.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to use the custom attribute for the donut chart item? Or are you using this as an example of creating your own custom view and asking how to add custom attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following line to your parent element in xml :

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 1):

This link will guide you: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

You need to define attrs.xml file as explained in the `Define Custom Attributes` section.

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 shows how to use the custom attribute. Unfortunately, the code snippets include literal HTML tags and entities. Here is a translated version:

```
<com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts.PieChart
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:id="@+id/piegraph"
           custom:pieInnerCircleRatio="128"/>
```